How can i make the ::ng-deep work only for one component
<igx-dialog igxOverlayOutlet #variantDialog class="variant-dialog">
  <div class="dialog-content">
    <div class="variant-options">
      <div class="variant-card">
        <img src="assets/images/variants/color_variant.png" alt="Color Variant" class="variant-image">
        <p class="variant-text">COLOR VARIANT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="variant-card">
        <img src="assets/images/variants/style_variant.png" alt="Style Variant" class="variant-image">
        <p class="variant-text">STYLE VARIANT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</igx-dialog>

SASS FIle
.dialog-content
display: flex
justify-content: center
align-items: center
width: 55vw
height: 55vh

.variant-options
display: flex
gap: 1rem

.variant-card
text-align: center
padding: 1rem
width: 100%
height: 100%
position: relative
background-color: transparent

.variant-image
max-width: 600px
max-height: 600px
border-radius: 15px

.variant-text
font-size: 4rem
line-height: normal
font-weight: bold
position: absolute
top: 30%
left: 5%
color: #3A3A3A

::ng-deep .variant-dialog .igx-dialog__window
background: transparent ! important
box-shadow: none ! important

::ng-deep .variant-dialog .igx-dialog__window doesn't affect the css at all,
but ::ng-deep .igx-dialog__window affects it.
Also tried with :host and that didn't solve the problem.
Host
For Host is says "Unknown CSS property 'host'" setting the :host doesn't how the warning anymore, and for underneeth the host it says "Illegal nesting: Only properties may be nested beneath properties"
So the question here is how can i encapsulate it without affecting other igx-dialogs.

just wrap the selector in :host :host ::ng-deep .igx-dialog__window

i mention it, doesn't work.

The :host tag, will ensure the dialog styles apply to only the children of the component, so the CSS is scoped to that component alone.
The ::ng-deep ensures the styles reach the dynamically created dialog elements.
    :host ::ng-deep .igx-dialog__window {
        background: transparent !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

Stackblitz Demo

If you are using multiple dialogs on the same component, then you can go for the below SCSS, where we first add a id to the dialog, so that it is unique and can be styled.
<igx-dialog
    #dialog1
    message="This will create a new social media account."
    id="custom-dialog-to-style"
>

Then, we use this ID, along with ::ng-deep and :host to make it apply to this element, then we use #custom-dialog-to-style to locate the particular dialog. We can use the CSS Next-sibling (+) Combinator (+) to get the next sibling, which is the modal, then we add the styles to it.
    :host
        ::ng-deep
        #custom-dialog-to-style
        ~ div.igx-overlay__wrapper--modal
        .igx-dialog__window {
        background: transparent !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

Stackblitz Demo
Finally your HTML might be incorrect, since the igxOverlayOutlet, should be the parent element of the igx-dialog, I may be wrong, but please use the stackblitz as code references.
    <div igxOverlayOutlet class="variant-dialog">
    <button igxButton="contained" igxRipple="white" (click)="openDialog()">
        Show Styled Dialog
    </button>
    <igx-dialog
        #dialog1
        message="This will create a new social media account."
        id="custom-dialog-to-style"
    >
        <igx-dialog-title>
        <div class="dialog-container">
            <igx-icon>account_box</igx-icon>
            <div class="dialog-title">Create a new account?</div>
        </div>
        </igx-dialog-title>
        <div igxDialogActions class="dialog-container dialog-actions">
        <button igxButton="contained" igxRipple="white" (click)="dialog.close()">
            CREATE
        </button>
        <button igxButton="contained" igxRipple="white" (click)="dialog.close()">
            CANCEL
        </button>
        </div>
    </igx-dialog>
    </div>


Im still having issues, this seems logical but still it wont apply the style.
:host
::ng-deep
#custom-dialog-to-style
~ div.igx-overlay__wrapper--modal
.igx-dialog__window
background: transparent !important
box-shadow: none !important
maybe i need to do something else to it? Maybe the logic is different on sass file, since :host wont apply because it give me illegal nesting. Thank you for replying so fast.

@Mali_Yuda please reproduce the issue in stackblitz and share back., that will lead you to the root cause

U were right, my mistake. Thank you so much man, u helped me alot

The only thing now is that when i close the dialog it shows the previous style and the dialog displays behind other components even tho i set the z-index, can i fix that somehow as well?

@Mali_Yuda could you replicate on the stackblitz, try to implement the same as what's on the stackblitz it will work then

I did tho, even on the stackblitz when u click close or create it will display the background before closing it, also i'm opening this dialog on another dialog and the custom dialog is displaying behind it.
